# How can I upgrade my below code into spring5.x from spring4.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to Upgrade my code from Spring 4.x version to Spring 5.x version but getting error due to parseStringValue method as it is removed in Spring5. the ${propertyPath} location is present in server I am running the file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name="load", value={"file:${propertyPath}/property.config"})
public class PropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
   private static Map propertiesMap;
 
   @Override
   protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
             Properties props) throws BeansException {
        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);
 
        propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = key.toString();
            propertiesMap.put(keyStr, parseStringValue(props.getProperty(keyStr),
                props, new HashSet()));
        }
    }
    public static String getProperty(String name) {
        return propertiesMap.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well dn't upgrade and use proper mechanisms instead? What is it you wanted to achieve in the first place? What you have here feels like you are working around the Spring properties injection/processing instead of working with it.

Comment: I tried using PropertyPlaceholderHelper , but then it is giving error in process property method

Comment: Due to security issue we have to update the spring version